# EJS not rendering HTML in between scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have the following code:

```
 <%
    // fetching from a cdn api
    cloudinary.api.resources(
    {
        type: 'upload',
        prefix: ''
    },
    (error, result) => {
      const assets = result.resources
      
      // console.log(assets)
      %>
      
      anything i have here isnt rendered
      
<% }) %>
```

I basically want to loop through each item in the assets array with a forEach and render them but it actually isn't rendering. Logging in the console works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**A different approach**. You can fetch assets before rendering your page(**res.render**) and then pass them as props when you are rendering that page. Like this:-

```
res.render("PATH",{assets:result.resources})
```

And then you can loop through assets array and code in ejs file looks like:-

```
<% assets.forEach(assest => { %>
              "MARKUP CODE"              
          <% }) %>
```

Comment: I want it to fetch the data everytime the page is refreshed so passing it as a prop won't work because then it will only refresh when the server is restarted

Comment: I don't think so because whenever you make a request to "/yourPage" it will make a request to API and fetch data in your controller and then again pass it to your ejs file as a prop so you don't need to restart the server again and again.